# javax (jws) WebService, obtener String de los parametros de entrada (Clave: valor)

Tags: java, webservice, soap

¡Hola!

Tengo un conjunto de servicios en Java, que los llamo por SOAP y quiero registrar los parámetros de entrada. Por ejemplo:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getObject")
public MyObject getObject(
        @WebParam(name = "param1") final Short param1,
        @WebParam(name = "param2") final Short param2,
        @WebParam(name = "param3") final Short param3,
        @WebParam(name = "param4") final Short param4,
        @WebParam(name = "param5") final Short param5,
        @WebParam(name = "param6") final Short param6,
        @WebParam(name = "param7") final Integer param7,
        @WebParam(name = "param8") final String param8,
        @WebParam(name = "param9") final Date param9,
        @WebParam(name = "param10") final Date param10,
        @WebParam(name = "param11") final Date param11,
        @WebParam(name = "param12") final Date param12)
```

Una vez en la función hago esto para recoger y guardar en un archivo de log lo que me ha entrado:

```
logTracking.request("param1: " + param1 + " - param2: " + param2
                + " - param3: " + param3 + " - param4: " + param4
                + " - param5: " + param5 + " - param6: " + param6
                + " - param7: " + param7 + " - param8: " + param8
                + " - param9: " + param9 + " - param10: " + param10
                + " - param11: " + param11 + " - param12: " + param12);
```

Tenemos muchos métodos y hacer en cada uno de estos, es engorroso, y cada vez que añada o elimine algun parámetro hay que cambiar también el log. (Evidentemente los parámetros tienen un nombre mas apropiado, lo pongo así a modo de ejemplo.)

¿Hay manera de recoger esto en una única cadena y así guardarlo en el log en formato String? He visto algo de `WebServiceContext`, he provado alguna cosa y no me ha funcionado, me viene siempre vacío o valores nulos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261348/how-can-i-access-the-servletcontext-from-within-a-jax-ws-web-service

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En mi caso, la forma de trabajar que tenemos es que las clases extiendan de Serializable, entonces a la hora de pintar el log, con pasar el objeto de la clase es suficiente.

Comment: @rencinas los parámetros son variables locales; no se serializan. Lo que se serializa son los atributos.

Comment: ¿Sobre qué plataforma trabajas? Yo lo que tengo hecho es hacer un log de toda la petición SOAP, no sé si es una solución aceptable.

Comment: @SJuan76, me parece bien lo que planteas, siempre y cuando pueda obtener los parámetros de entrada. ¿Cómo se hace? Trabajamos sobre un servidor de Payara.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción serían los `Handler`s, que son el equivalente en JAX-WS a los `HttpFilter`; pequeños módulos que se ejecutan antes o después de la lógica principal.

```
public class SOAPLogger implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{
  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
      SOAPMessage soapMessage = context.getMessage();
      ...
  }
}
```

A partir de aquí puedes jugar con `soapMessage` para extraer el SOAP (o si lo prefieres, hacer un recorrido más fino del contenido de la petición). Por ejemplo, con `getSOAPBody`, `getSOAPPart`, etc.

Los handlers van en "cadenas" de handler, que se declaran en un fichero:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains
   xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <javaee:handler-chain>
      <javaee:handler>
         <javaee:handler-class>miPackage.SOAPLogger</javaee:handler-class>
     </javaee:handler>
   </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

Para indicar que un WS usa un `handler chain`, usas `@HandlerChain`

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")
public class MiWebService{

   @WebMethod(operationName = "getObject")
   public MyObject getObject(
```

Más información: 
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/

---

Otra opción, mucho más sencilla pero mucho menos flexible, es usar el sistema de logs que pueda ofrecer la plataforma. Por ejemplo en WildFly, en el fichero `logging.properties`:

```
logger.org.apache.cxf.services.MiWebService.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.cxf.services.MiWebService.useParentHandlers=true
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he estado probando y parece que el servidor que tenemos de Payara y el HandlerChain no se llevan bien, me da errores a patadas por eso y la primera línea del servidor es: _GRAVE:   Component referenced from annotation symbol cannot be found
 symbol: javax.jws.HandlerChain_ en el momento del import, supongo que no hay otra que ir "picando" los parámetros a mano, tal y como estamos haciendo hasta ahora.